# chrome extension activates on all websites how to enable it for a specific website

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to activate the chrome extension for a specific website however, it activates for all the websites.

Here is my code :

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "CHANGE THIS : Extension boilerplate",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon19.png",
    "default_title": "page action demo",
    "default_popup": "src/bg/popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "url",
    "webRequest",
    "declarativeContent",
    "downloads",
    "storage",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["src/bg/background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```

What I tried - I used `page_action` however if I used it then the content in my `popup.html` file is not visible. I even replaced the url in the `permissions` to `https://www.google.com/` to check whether I'm entering any wrong patterns however, that was not even working. I even surfed various answers as well but they are not properly guided and I'm new to chrome extension. So, I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated !